# What is the meaning of IO Block and how is it calculated?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

I'd like to know what the meaning of "IO Block" is in the output of `stat` and how that number is calculated.

I know that the physical size of a folder/file is measured in 4096 byte blocks.

However in this example below, the size of the file is more than 4096 bytes and the value of "IO Block" has not changed.

What is the meaning of IO blocks and how to change it?

```
stat yeni
  File: 'yeni'
  Size: 12890           Blocks: 32          IO Block: 4096   normal dosya
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 2255976     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   ihsan)   Gid: ( 1000/   ihsan)
Access: 2017-08-15 20:07:26.324017949 +0300
Modify: 2017-08-15 20:06:30.703053636 +0300
Change: 2017-08-15 20:07:26.324017949 +0300
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 6):

## Short explanation

- "IO Block" in `stat`'s output is the preferred number of bytes that the file system uses for reading and writing files. An IO Block is commonly **4096 bytes**.
- "Blocks", on the other hand, counts how many **512-bytes** blocks are allocated on disk for the file.

## More detailed explanation

### "IO Block" vs. "Blocks"

#### IO Block

"IO Block" is the preferred number of bytes that the file system uses for reading and writing files.

This number is fixed to 4096 bytes on my ext4 partition.

A block size of 4096 bytes is also the default for file systems between 512 MB and 4 TB. See [`man mke2fs.conf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/mke2fs.conf.5.html#THE_%5Bfs_types%5D_STANZA), your `/etc/mke2fs.conf`, and the documentation of the `-T` option in [`man mkfs.ext4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4).

#### Blocks

On the other hand, "Blocks" gives the number of **512-byte** blocks allocated for the file on disk. Note that the blocks of `stat`'s "Blocks" have a different size than the blocks from "IO Block":

- number of bytes in a block of "IO Block": Defined by the file system. 4096 bytes in your and my case.
- number of bytes in a block of "Blocks": Always 512 bytes.

### How do we know what "IO Block" and "Blocks" really refer to?

Digging through [`stat`'s source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/00ea4bacf6063ccc125209d5186f8f2382c6f0d4/src/stat.c#L1633) we find this line that creates the default output of `stat`:

```
Size: %-10s\tBlocks: %-10b IO Block: %-6o %F\n\
```

Picking it apart:

`Size: %-10s`: "Size:" prints the size of the file in bytes, with some padding using `-10`.

`Blocks: %-10b`: "Blocks" prints the value of placeholder `%b` (with some padding). What's `%b`? According to [`man 1 stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html):

> %b     number of blocks allocated (see %B)

Have a look at `%B`:

> %B     the size in bytes of each block reported by %b

How many bytes are in a block denoted by "Blocks"?

```
stat --format="%B" ~/small_file
```

This prints "512". Alright, the block size of "Blocks" is 512 bytes.

On to the code that prints "IO Block":

`IO Block: %-6o`: What's the placeholder `%o`? Straight from `man 1 stat`:

> %o     optimal I/O transfer size hint

Interesting! "IO Block" is short for "optimal I/O transfer size hint".

Running this on an ext4 file system:

```
stat --format="%o" ~/small_file
```

we learn the "IO Block" is 4096 bytes. That's quite a size difference:

- "IO Block": 4096 bytes
- "Blocks":   512  bytes

Putting it all together:

```
stat --format="File is %s bytes but needs %B*%b bytes on disk. Optimal I/O transfer size hint (alias IO Block): %o bytes" ~/small_file
```

Which prints the following in my case:

> File is 116 bytes but needs 512*8 bytes on disk. Optimal I/O transfer size hint (alias IO Block): 4096 bytes

It's easy to [make](https://linuxize.com/post/stat-command-in-linux/) the [mistake](https://www.howtogeek.com/451022/how-to-use-the-stat-command-on-linux/) of thinking that the Blocks value counts the number of IO Blocks allocated on disk.

#### `stat` the system call

From [`man 2 stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) we can learn more about the IO transfer size hint, also known as "IO Block":

> The st_blksize field gives the "preferred" blocksize for efficient file system I/O. (Writing to a file in smaller chunks may cause an inefficient read-modify-rewrite.)

Also citing from [`man 2 stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) that describes the field `st_blocks` which is useful to understand `stat`'s "Blocks":

> This field indicates the number of blocks allocated to the file, in 512-byte units.

#### More examples with `stat`

Here is shortened example output of `stat ~/small_file`:

```
File: /home/mb/small_file
Size: 116           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
// Rest omitted
```

- `Size: 116` means there are 116 bytes of data in this file. But it doesn't tell us how many bytes are used to store this file on disk. That's what "Blocks" is for.
- `Blocks: 8` means this file takes up 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes on disk. Given that the file only has 116 bytes of data, this is a little wasteful. But we can't use fewer bytes since the block size of ext4 on my system is 4096 bytes. How wasteful? Let's calculate: `116 / 4096 * 100 ≈ 2.8` meaning only about 2.8% of the allocated bytes are actually used for storing the file's data.
- `IO Block: 4096` means the preferred number of bytes that are read or written from the disk at once.

Another example with a slightly larger file, `stat ~/larger_file`:

```
File: /home/mb/larger_file
Size: 91246         Blocks: 184        IO Block: 4096   regular file
// Rest omitted
```

- `Size: 91246` tells us the number of bytes in this file, independent of our file system and the number of bytes it physically occupies on disk.
- `Blocks: 184` lets us calculate the number of bytes this file physically occupies on disk: 184 * 512 = 94208 bytes. How many of those allocated bytes are used for actually storing `larger_file`'s data? `91246 / 94208 * 100 ≈ 96.9`. About 96.6% is the file's data, that's much more efficient compared to our previous example with `~/small_file`.

### Changing value of "IO Block"

I doubt you can change the value of "IO Block" of an *existing* file system. [Here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145241/how-to-set-block-size-using-blockdev-command) a discussion on that.

In case you are creating a *new* file system, there's the [`-b` option](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) that specifies the block size in bytes.

```
mkfs.ext4 -b 2048 /dev/sdb1
```

From the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4):

> Valid block-size values are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block.

Comment: This is a wonderfully comprehensive, thoughtful and well-referenced answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linux file systems are separated to 4 major parts .

1. Boot Block
2. Super Block
3. I-List
4. Data Block

In super block there is parameter by the name of Block Size which means that Linux separate Disk to 4096 block block . As you may know disk in Block Device ( check `ll /dev/sda` and see *b* at left ) and you read block from disk not just character . So I/O block means file system read every 4096 block while reading a part of disk . It doesn't relate to file size . For changing BS you should train file system to read smaller or larger blocks ( It is not recommended ) .